# what is the new version of NBZIMM package for R 4.1.3

Tags: r, r-package

I have been having problems finding old packages for new nersion of R, any help appreciated

```
> install.packages('NBZIMM')
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘NBZIMM’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

This was never on CRAN (or Bioconductor) are another curated R package repository.
You do find it on github, though:

and this should even build the vignettes:

```r
if(!require("remotes")) install.packages("remotes") # from CRAN
install.packages("R.rsp")# from CRAN; to build NBZIMM vignettes

remotes::install_github("nyiuab/NBZIMM")
```